# Scanner method and string pool

Tags: java

The script below will compare two string to see if they are equal. In this case one string is declared and the other string is input from the scanner. I understand  why these two string are not equal when compared (say aName = test and anotherName= test) because they will contain different references addresses.

This next paragraph will lead into my question. The nextLine() method returns a string. I know normally if two strings contain the same text they would have the same address in the string pool. **So my question is, why isn't the string returned from the nextLine() method to the anotherName variable assigned to the string pool and given the same address as aName, since they have the same text? ***

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TryToCompareString
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String aName = "test";
String anotherName;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your name");
anotherName = input.nextLine();


if (aName == anotherName)
{
System.out.println(aName + " equals " + anotherName);
}
else
{
System.out.println(aName + " does not equal " + anotherName);
}
}
}
```

Comment: If you didn't input `test` then would you ever expect the references to be the same?  In any case, if the `Scanner` uses `new String("test")` to martial the input, I'm not sure it matters even if the pool already has this text.

Comment: "I know normally if two strings contain the same text they would have the same address" that is only true in case of *literals* which by default are using string pool and this makes sense because same strings tend to exist in code few times so having many string objects representing same text wouldn't make sense. But in case of reading text from external resource caching them in String pool wouldn't make much sense either, since it is very unlikely that same line would appear often, so sting interring wasn't added here which is why `nextLine()` returns new string object.

Comment: I am still a beginner. I was looking at the nextLine method and didn't really see where it was creating a new String object within the method.